# Kotlin KFunction reflection - get parameter values

Tags: reflection, kotlin

In order to create a simple annotation that logs function calls, I'm trying to grab the following attributes from a function that has said annotation:

- Function name
- Parameter names
- Parameter values

What I have so far uses `KCallable` as a value, which makes grabbing the name and names from the list of `KParameter` fairly simple. However, I cannot figure out how to get the values of said parameters to make the log statement more contextual.

Does anyone have ideas on grabbing these parameters values within the annotation? It doesn't need to use `KCallable`, that just seemed like the most intuitive receiver.

Comment: You can't do that with reflection, because parameters are different every time. In order to achieve this you need to place the log function inside that called function and pass the values. There's no other way that I'm aware of

Comment: @Mibac I was hoping with an annotation having runtime retention maybe this would be possible, but unfortunately you may be right.

Comment: Annotations must have static values as well. You can't change annotation's value during runtime

Comment: The difference here is that `KCallable` represents the function as a whole, not a specific invocation. The function as a whole does not have parameter values. Just like a `Class` instance cannot know the values of it's instance fields.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a different approach. Annotations and parameter type are a compile time features while values are a runtime feature.

What you will have to do is use a bytecode processing framework like ASM or google "aspect oriented programming". That allows you to examine the generated bytecode and modify if before the JVM tries to execute it.

The other approach is to write a Kotlin compiler plugin which generates the necessary code (google "Writing Your First Kotlin Compiler Plugin")

This blog post contains an example for Java and Spring using the AOP approach: https://solocoding.dev/blog/eng_spring_centrlize_logging_with_aop

I recommend the compiler plugin because the other approach is much more complicated, brittle and badly documented. Use AOP only if you find a framework which already contains all the features you need.